# populate kendo gridview on selection of kendo dropdownlist

Tags: kendo-ui

how to pass the selected value of Kendo dropdownlist as parameter to function(Action) which populates the Kendo gridview using .net mvc 4?

Regard
User

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

read method of your grid

```
.Read(read => read.Action("GetAllMessage", "Account").Data("getMsgType")).PageSize(10)
```

this is function which will read dropdownlist value;

```
    function getMsgType()
{
    return {
        SpecialityIn: $("#MsgType").val()
    };
}
```

$("#MsgType") will be your dropdownListId

handel change event of dropdown as

```
 @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.MsgType)
                .Events(events=>events.Change("OnMsgTypeChange"))
                        .Name("MsgType")
                        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:200px;font-size:12px;margin-top:6px;" })
                        .DataTextField("Description")
                        .DataValueField("MsgType")
                        .DataSource(source => { source.Read(read => { read.Action("readMsgType", "Account") })})
                        .OptionLabel("Select")
                        .Enable(false)
                        .AutoBind(true)

                )
```

bind grid on onChageEevent of grid as

```
 function OnMsgTypeChange() {
    $("#GridMsgList").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

did you try kendo UI dropdown list Event

http://demos.kendoui.com/web/dropdownlist/events.html

```
 function onSelect(e) {
                        if ("kendoConsole" in window) {
                            var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item.index());
                            kendoConsole.log("event :: select (" + dataItem.text + " : " + dataItem.value + ")" );
                        }
                    };

 $("#dropdownlist").kendoDropDownList({
                        dataTextField: "text",
                        dataValueField: "value",
                        dataSource: data,
                        select: onSelect
                    });
```